# append a blob in app engine using java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blob

Is it possible to send two files to a single blob before the blob is closed in app engine?Can we append a blob content?.I read that the blob needs to be finalized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, blobs are write-only and you can append data to them (even in separate requests) until you call finalize. Then they became read-only.

Comment: the blob is not finalized.now how to call the blob?

Comment: In the first request you need to get a path to the blob and save it, then use it in second request to append: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore